# Replacing country-pairs value with if condition

Tags: international-economics, stata

for my Master thesis, I am working with Stata and I am trying to replace countries-pair values equal to the values of other countries-pairs. I start presenting my data: *regulatory distance* is a bilateral index that tells how distant are the regulations between two countries and it ranges from 0 to 1; *eu_imp* (*eu_exp*) is a dummy variable equal to 1 if the *importer* (*exporter*) is a European country, 0 otherwise. The problem is that this index (regulatory distance) does present values for European Union as a whole (EUN) but it does not for single European countries (ex: EST, ITA, FRA,...). Thus, I would like to replace the bilateral value of all European importers (eu_imp =1) equal to the correspondent bilateral values for EUN. For instance, from this:

[image: importer exporter regulatory distance eu_imp eu_exp year ITA USA . 1 0 2010 ITA ZAF . 1 0 2010 RUS USA 0.46 0 0 2010 EUN USA 0.25 1 0 2010 EUN ZAF 0.36 1 0 2010]

to this

[image: importer exporter regulatory distance eu_imp eu_exp year ITA USA 0.25 1 0 2010 ITA ZAF 0.36 1 0 2010 RUS USA 0.46 0 0 2010 EUN USA 0.25 1 0 2010 EUN ZAF 0.36 1 0 2010]

I am really confused about how to get this result. Since I have been stuck on this for a long time, I hope there is someone who can help to solve this issue.

Comment: Given its focus on coding, I suggest to move this question to Statalist of stack overflow.